# AJAX jQuery PHP Get JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a problem with getting a JSON object from a server. The PHP returns a JSON file.

The script always fails and I have no idea why. The PHP when ran in a browser returns this;

```
{"accountDetails":[{"account_name":"SOMEACCOUNT","auto_id":"1"}
```

My code:

```
   <div id="output"> This should change </div>

    <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'selectAccounts.php',
                data: "",
                dataType: 'json',

                success: function ()
                {
                    $("#output").text("SUCEEDED");
                },

                error: function () {
                    $("#output").text("UNSUCEEDED");
                }
            });
        });

    </script>
```

Comment: What does your browser console say?

Comment: Have you watched the request / response in your console to make sure that the PHP is returning the data to the browser?

Comment: Your JSON is missing a couple of closing brackets.

Comment: Your JSON is invalid (missing a `]}`). I'm not sure if this is a typo in the question, or the reason your code isn't working.

Comment: Also check out http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: sorry that is a typo (only a snippet) @matt

Comment: this is also using jquery mobile and phonegap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can parse the errors like

```
error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus,errorThrown){ /* render that stuff */}
```